# Documentation for Airflow HTTP Operator/Sensor Extra Options?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to read into the extra_options setting for Airflow to see what properties are possible to set (mainly interested in http timeout). I can't find any supporting documentation for this specific param anywhere: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/code.html?highlight=requests#airflow.operators.SimpleHttpOperator.

Has anyone worked with this before and is able to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [source code](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/_modules/http_hook.html#HttpHook) (`airflow.hooks.http_hook.HttpHook.run_and_check`) `extra_options` uses these parameters:

> ```
>         response = session.send(
>             prepped_request,
>             stream=extra_options.get("stream", False),
>             verify=extra_options.get("verify", False),
>             proxies=extra_options.get("proxies", {}),
>             cert=extra_options.get("cert"),
>             timeout=extra_options.get("timeout"),
>             allow_redirects=extra_options.get("allow_redirects", True))
> ```

You can read more about them in [requests library docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.request):

- `stream` – (optional) whether to immediately download the response content. Defaults to False.
- `verify` – (optional) Either a boolean, in which case it controls whether we verify the server’s TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it must be a path to a CA bundle to use. Defaults to True.
- `proxies` – (optional) Dictionary mapping protocol or protocol and hostname to the URL of the proxy.
- `cert` – (optional) if String, path to ssl client cert file (.pem). If Tuple, (‘cert’, ‘key’) pair.
- `timeout` (float or tuple) – (optional) How long to wait for the server to send data before giving up, as a float, or a (connect timeout, read timeout) tuple.
- `allow_redirects` (bool) – (optional) Set to True by default.

Answer (score 2):

Following this trail of links in [Airflow's source-code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/v1-10-stable), you can easily determine what all things can be passed in `SimpleHttpOperator`, or more specifically, in [`extra` field](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models/connection.py#L127) of [`Http` `Connection`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models/connection.py#L75). I'm hereby adding trail of calls in Airflow's source that I used to trace the usage of `extra_options`

- [`extra_options` are passed](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L89) to `run()` method of `HttpHook`
- `run()` method of `HttpHook` [passes those `extra_options`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py#L132) to `run_and_check()` method
- `run_and_check()` method [extracts variety of information](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/http_hook.py#L169) from `extra_options`, as shown in the source-code snippet below

> ```
> try:
>     response = session.send(
>         prepped_request,
>         stream=extra_options.get("stream", False),
>         verify=extra_options.get("verify", False),
>         proxies=extra_options.get("proxies", {}),
>         cert=extra_options.get("cert"),
>         timeout=extra_options.get("timeout"),
>         allow_redirects=extra_options.get("allow_redirects", True))
>
>     if extra_options.get('check_response', True):
>         self.check_response(response)
>     return response
>
> except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as ex:
>     self.log.warning(str(ex) + ' Tenacity will retry to execute the operation')
>     raise ex
> ```